# Self employed as IT consultant and as massage therapist: Do I need 2 HST numbers?

Tags: canada, hst

I am self employed as an IT consultant and now also as a registered massage therapist.

My combined earnings are over $30K annually.

Do I need to get a 2nd HST number for the massage therapy income?

Comment: Do you run these as two separate businesses, with two separate registrations and two separate business licenses? Or just as one?

Comment: There are no business registrations i.e. I do not have a numbered business. The only license is a certification/registration # through the ontario massage therapy self-regulatory body, which has nothing to do with taxes.

Answer (score 1):

Given your clarifying points, it sounds like you are running both businesses as one combined business. As such, you should be able to get just a single HST number and use that.

However, let me please urge you to contact a professional accountant and possibly a lawyer, as it is very unusual to be performing these services without a business license, and you may be exposing yourself to civil penalties and placing your personal assets (e.g. your house) at risk. Additionally, it may be beneficial for you to run these as businesses as you can likely write off (more of) your expenses.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the HST answer. Yes, I could reduce liability by INCORPORATING (not via 'license'), though this is not generally financially sensible when income is so low. Also, there is no such thing as a license for doing IT work - perhaps you are thinking of P.Eng? I am able to write off all the expenses I have without incorporating.

Comment: I am not thinking of a professional license, I am thinking of a business license, a permit to run your business. http://services.bizpal-perle.ca/eng/?b=35 may help you determine if you need permits. All or almost all municipalities in Canada require a business license/business permit to operate, and may require additional permits.

Comment: Thanks for the link. No, no operating licenses required (unless I want to use public spaces, or bid for federal govt contracts, or change building usage/zoning, handle dangerous goods, provide public transportation, change plumbing, operate offroad/airborne vehicles etc.)